# $('myTextBox').val(); undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html tag:

```
<input type="number" id="priority" value="50" min="1" max="100">
```

My javascript code:

```
var $value = $('priority');
alert($value.val());
```

This alerts undefined and I can't figure out why.

When I get rid of .val() it alerts [object Object]

```
alert($value);
```

Comment: `var $value = $('#priority');`

Comment: Time to [learn about how selectors work in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). To get an element with an id, use `$('#priority')`

Comment: If you omit the `#` (id selector) or `.` (class selector) jquery is looking for elements called `<priority>`.

Comment: The OP already knows how to select by ID. This is just a typo, and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find element by id, you need to add a leading `#`, by class name a dot:

```js
var $value = $('#priority');
alert($value.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="priority" value="50" min="1" max="100">
```

This [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp) might be helpful.

Comment: OMG I didn't even see that.